# How can I change what columns are visible in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, memory, task-manager

I am missing the Memory category tab in Task Manager.

[image: Task Manager]

How can I make it re-appear? Or what can I do to add/remove a column?

Comment: `View` > `Select Columns` The default memory one is `Memory - Private Working Set` I'll leave it to @Tom to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on **View**.
2. Click on **Select Columns**.
   [image]
3. Check the box next to **Memory - Private Working Set**.
   [image]
4. Close the dialog by clicking **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

The preceding answers are fine for the memory columns in the Processes tab, but not for the "missing memory category tab".

The OP seems to be looking for a "Memory" tab, alongside "Applications", "Processes", "Services", etc.

There isn't one.

What you're looking for is under the "Performance" tab. Go there, then click "Resource Monitor". There you will find your "Memory" tab.